# Unity capsule collider not working while animating

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I have a fairly simple setup that involves multiple capsule colliders to detect the collision. 
[image]

But while punching opponent collision detection is working but attackers hand is moving through opponent body. 
[image]

**WHAT I DID TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM**

1. Reduced speed of the animation.
2. Non kinematic rigidbody is already added to component.
3. Changed collision detection to continuous and dynamic-continuous.

Also root motion is enabled.

What's the reason for this behaviour? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you tell us where are the colliders during the animation? Does the enemy have a collider?

Comment: yeah enemy also have same collider setup

Comment: Still you didn't answer the first question